# Why Everything has exchanged places on my android Interface?

Tags: malware, user-interface

Well, I don't know how but today suddenly my first (and new) android phone (Moto E) got "sick" and everything on both the sides of the interface switched places. It is like reflection about vertical axis.
I mean everything looks fine except that,...

- operations for which I previously used my Right-Hand, Right-Thumb, etc., I now have to use my Left-Hand, Left-Thumb etc.
- Things that were displayed Left aligned previously, are now being displayed Right-aligned. **Text Alignment changed**.
- The swipe that worked rightward previously is now changed to Leftward. **Swapped direction of swipe**.
- the signs that were previously on Top-Right (battery, time etc.), now have **swapped their positions** with signs on top-left (notifications and stuff).
- Memory status that increased rightward, is increasing leftward.

And I am also seeing **occasional glitches in the graphics** here and there. One of such is that **only half of the context menu appear** within ES file browser, when mobile is held horizontally. It seems that it is because its shape is not getting updated while the interface turns 90 degrees.

Is it due to some virus? I recently **allowed app form unknown resources** to install adobe flash (that didn't work, btw). I also have **changed my runtime from Dalvik to ART**.

Please tell me how to fix this...Thnk you!

**Edit:** I changed from Dalvik to ART 4 days ago and till today morning, everything was **fabulous**. Today I updated chrome and installed pocketbook app. And out of nowhere doom struck my humble mobile. Also "Mirroring" is indeed there but only of the relative position of elements.

Comment: Do you mean mirrored? Could you add a screenshot and link it here? Probably "Force RtL" is set unknowingly/accidentally.

Comment: Mightbe due to the fact that you changed your runtime. I am using kitkat (4.4.1), and last time i changed my runtime, i had unexpected errors and had to factory reset the device to solve it

Comment: @Wall-e you might want to take a look at [this page](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) as it appears you have managed to create 2 accounts.

Comment: Thanks guys...I guess before enabling the developer option, I should have gained more experience in "development" first. :)